# Python Webscraping with BS4 and html not downloading correctly

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

I've been trying to web scrape information off the website:
https://www.tddirectinvesting.co.uk/share-dealing/daily-trading-ideas

And the information I wanted were in the  elements, with the class of "RecogniaEventSummaryBodyLinks"

But when I tried to  download the html file and print it, it showed that the html file didn't download correctly. What I mean by this is that when I copied and pasted the whole html text I got from my python code into notepad++ and did CTRL+F to find if these  elements were in the html text, they weren't there.

I also tried manually downloading the file directly from the website, but this also didn't work either.

Heres my code (python):

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def viewPage(url,proxy,userAgent):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cookieJar)
    br.set_proxies(proxy)
    br.addheaders = userAgent
    page = br.open(url)
    htmlFile = page.read()
    for cookie in cookieJar:
          print("cookie:  " + str(cookie))
          print("")
    return htmlFile

def ScrapeFigures(url):
    html = viewPage(url,proxyAdress,agentStringSample)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    info = soup.find("a",attrs={"class":"RecogniaEventSummaryBodyLinks"})
```

I tried printing out variable `info`, but it returned null.

However, after this I tried copy & pasting the python output for the whole `soup` variable in the above code into another text file, and saved it as a html file. When I opened this html file with my web browser (Chrome), the elements I needed were on the page, despite not being present in the html file in text format. So I just wondered, is this caused by some sort of JS in the background thats triggered when the page is opened?

My question is, how can I scrape off the  elements described above? Is there a way to get around this weird bug?

Thank you for your time

Comment: since js/ajax populates the live HTML page at the url, you need to collect the info from where's it available: client-side JS (not python). you might also look closely at the devtool's connections tab while the page loads; if the data is not in the initial serve, but is in there later,  it probably comes in structured from an API that you might be able to call directly from python and not even have to scrape (xml, json, etc)!

Comment: You could use sellenium to allow the JS to run or revers access the api from python.